# Get random element from hashset?

Tags: c#, random, hashset

Im using the following piece of code to load my text file into a **hashset**.

```
HashSet<string> hashs = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadLines("textFile.txt"));
```

Am wondering if there is any easy way to get a random line from it?

Lets asume the textFile.txt contains 10 lines, i would like to randomize and grab one of those existing lines.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried using the System.Random class to generate a random number between 0 an <# of lines> and then referencing that item by index?  Those are all tasks already documented at the MSDN library.  http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Random randomizer = new Random();
string[] asArray = hashs.ToArray()
string randomLine = asArray[randomizer.Next(asArray.length)];
```

Comment: Quite inefficient performance wise.  Not that I know a better way, but just saying.

Answer (score 39):

a simple answer like the accepted one is possible without enumerating the entire array every time:

```
private static readonly Random     random  = new Random();
private static readonly HashSet<T> hashset = new HashSet<T>();

...

T element = hashset.ElementAt(random.Next(hashset.Count));
```

Comment: ElementAt still enumerates elements until it reaches specified index, so it's not going to be blazingly faster.

Comment: If hashsets elements change in a multi-threaded environment this can return InvalidOperationException (Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.) This can be avoided by either using a lock(object) on the .ElementAt line or .ToArray() the hashset and store as new variable use that one for the rand Count AND for the .ElementAt but this may not be memory efficient

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a random number between 0 and the size of the set, then iterate through the set up until you reach the item whose index is the same as the generated number.  Then select this item as the random element

Comment: how would the code for that look? not sure how to write that :)

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe a more general solution for any enumerable

```
public static class RandomExtensions
{
    private static readonly Random rnd = new Random();
    private static readonly object sync = new object();

    public static T RandomElement<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable) {
        if (enumerable == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("enumerable");

        var count = enumerable.Count();

        var ndx = 0;
        lock (sync) 
            ndx = rnd.Next(count); // returns non-negative number less than max

        return enumerable.ElementAt(ndx); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `ElementAt` will throw exception for empty collection.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky If ElementAt throws, than RandomElement should also throw the same exception. There should be a RandomElementOrDefault in this case

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on drawing multiple random values, the efficient way would be to use a Dictionary with integer keys to store the information.

```
HashSet<string> hashs = new HashSet<string>();
Dictionary<int, string> lookup = new Dictionary<int, string>();
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("textFile.txt")) {
    if (hashs.Add(line)) {
        lookup.Add(lookup.Count, line);
    }
}
        
int randomInt = new Random().Next(lookup.Count);
string randomLine = lookup[randomInt];
```

(In this example, you could use a List instead, but with a dictionary you can also remove individual elements without affecting the order).

Answer (score -1):

Since .Net Framework 3.5 you can use Linq with its [`Enumerable.First()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first) extension method.
Without specifying any condition as parameter this method will return

> the first element of a sequence.

You should consider that using `Enumerable.First()` requires your `HashSet<>` to contain at least one element.
To check this precondition you could either use `HashSet<>.Count` or via Linq with [`Enumerable.Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any) again without specifying a condidion.

```
HashSet<T> hashSet = new HashSet<T>();

...

if(hashSet.Any())
{
  T randomElement = hashSet.First()
}
```

As an alternative to the approach above you could use [`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault) if you would like to retrieve any default value in case the `HashSet<T>` is empty.

```
T randomElement = hashSet.FirstOrDefault(default(T));
```

Comment: How will this return a **random** item?

Comment: @derHugo HashSet is an unsorted structure, so first will be random

Comment: @orion_tvv I guess it will still return the same element for each time you call this ... random != unsorted

Comment: Yes, if you want to get different item by multiple calls you shouldn't use HashSet and you have to pay for converting into array-like structure. But for most use cases first item is good tradeoff