# Do not repeat words from the file

Tags: c#

I have a problem with duplicating and repeating words.

I have a `file.txt` that contains multiple words some of them are duplicated.

What I wanted to do is to get random words from `file.txt` and if the string has been picked previously ignore and pick another word.

For example:

My file contains => "Hello", "Morning", "Hello", "Hi", "Drink", "Cola"

and I get a random string:

```cs
public string[] _randomString;
public Random _randomText = new Random();
(...)

public void randomClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    _path = "C:\\test\\file.txt"
    _randomString = File.ReadAllLines(_path);
    _result.Text = _randomString[_randomText.Next(_randomString.Lenght)];
}
```

and what I want to do is:

If the word `Hello` appears again - continue, if it appears first time - shown in `_result.Text`

But if all words have been picked from `file.txt` - `_result.Text = "All words was shown"`

I've tried many options but nothing works for me.

Comment: If you file is line-delimited, you can simply use `File.ReadAllLines(_path).Distinct().ToList()`.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve this yourself?  Please edit you question and add in the code segment that demonstrates your best attempt at resolving this and then explain at what point in your code you aren't getting the results you expect.

Comment: You say 'get random words', so you appear to be running your method more than once. If that's the case, you will have to keep track somewhere of what words you have already supplied, and then compare your new 'random' word against the history, and go again if it exists in the history. An alternative approach would be to generate a unique list of words (`GroupBy` could do this) and store that *in random order* in a stack or a list or something, and then pull off of the stack as requested.

Comment: Alternatively you can use a string that is [almost] guaranteed to never be repeated. Guid.NewGuid().ToString(). But if you must, another option is to store each word in a set  (ex HashSet) which allows you to check against the set if your word was already touched before. You must ensure that checks and entries must all be in the same case (upper/lower).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of issues in your code. Beyond the typos, it is hard to understand what your code actually looks like. I will assume you meant something like this:

```
class YourClass
{
    public string[] _randomString;
    public Random _randomText = new Random();
    private Result _result;
    private string _path;

    public void ShowAllWordsInRandomOrder()
    {
        _path = "C:\\test\\file.txt";
        _randomString = File.ReadAllLines(_path);
        _result.Text = _randomString[_randomText.Next(_randomString.Length)];
     }

}
```

Your first obvious problem is that you are only showing one word. If you wanted to show all of them you would have to iterate through all the words.
It sounds like your next issue is that you need to get only the distinct values from the file. Here's a variation of your code that addresses these issues. I have taken the liberty to do some basic code cleanup for you as well:

```
    class YourClass
    {
        private Result _result;
        private const string _path = "C:\\test\\file.txt";
        private List<string> _words;
        private readonly Random _random = new();

        public void Setup() // call this method before the first time your button is clicked
        {
            _words = File.ReadAllLines(_path).Distinct().ToList();
        }
        void OnButtonClick()
        {
            var text = "All words was shown";
            var words = _words;
            if (words.Any())
            {
                var index = _random.Next(0, words.Count - 1);
                text = words[index];
                words.RemoveAt(index);
            }
            _result.Text = text;
        }

    }
```

Edit: I have updated the code to account for your comment

Comment: I thought that my code will be a mess and I'm thankful for cleaning it up.
You've mostly right about my code but (I forgot to write it down, my bad) I'm using the button to display text. I've tried your solution and only one word is shown and after pressing the again button nothing changes. I've edited my question to me more readable.

Comment: @JohnDown I have updated my answer to account for the button press. It should work now

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HashSet<string>` it will store only unique items.
So, you can do this :

```
var hashSetLines  = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadAllLines(_path));
_randomString = hashSetLines.ToArray();
_result.Text = _randomString[_randomText.Next(_randomString.Lenght)];
```

Comment: This is an O(n^2) solution to an O(n) problem. It may not matter if the file is small, but if the file size is large this will be very slow and consume lots of memory. I recommend using a List<string> instead because it is both  more efficient and simpler.

Comment: @NigelBess actually, using `HashSet` is direct while `Distinct()` is indirect since both are using `Set` with iterators internally. almost every `Linq` extension uses iterator, so that's why I went with the direct approach. If memory concerns you, then streaming the file would be way more efficient then storing the file content.

Comment: memory is not so much the concern as time actually. For every item in the `HashSet` you are creating a new array with the size of the remaining items in the `HashSet`. `HashSet` is my preferred data structure for this type of problem actually, but the problem is that you are generating a new array every time you index. Might as well use a linked list then.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15960061/9884514) may actually be the best solution. Keep using `HashSet` but index it with `ElementAt`.